# How do I quit a wxWidget application when no window was opened?

Tags: wxwidgets

I have written a wxWidget gui application. Depending on the parameters, a gui is displayed in some cases, but when the program is run in silent mode, it will just perform it's task without opening a window.

I could return `false` in my `App::OnInit()` override, and the application will terminate, but then the exit code is also set to indicate that something went wrong.

So how do I properly exit in such a case, resp. how can I set the returncode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enter the main event loop, as it happens if you return `true` from `YourApp::OnInit()`, you must exit it to terminate the application. This is done using [ExitMainLoop()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_app_console.html#ad0f1e724efa8ae1e94cde655c74c85dc) which is usually called when the last top level window is deleted, but can also be called manually.

If you don't enter the main loop event at all, then returning `false` from `YourApp::OnInit()` is the simplest way to exit the program immediately but, as you already know, this indicates a failure to initialize the application, from wxWidgets point of view, and so by default the program exits with non-zero exit code. To return your own exit code, continue to return `true` from `OnInit()` and override [OnRun()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_app_console.html#ac05a28c7cdb529f2cdfe77b3431c385c), which is called next if `OnInit()` succeeded, and simply return the code from there, without doing anything, especially not calling the base class version which would enter the main event loop.

Comment: I tested this, but this doesn't work. I assume that exiting the main loop doesn't work, because the main loop probalby doesn't exist yet, before a window is opened.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize you wanted to exit immediately and not at some later time, when the main loop is already running. I'll update my answer to cover this case too.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation here: http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxappoverview.html

I think wxExit might be what you're looking for, though the documentation says to only use it in emergencies.

Comment: This doesn't work either. At least it's not different from returning false. :) It seems that wxWidgets doesn't provide a way to cleanly exit without opening a window first.